What is Poirot saying about the feather pen in "The Murder of Roger Ackroyd"?

Poirot held up the feather pen, and Kent reached for it.
"It is for your drugs, isn't it? You dropped it in the summerhouse at Fernly Park last Friday night."

This is from a simplified version of Agatha Christie's novel The Murder of Roger Ackroyd. I can't understand how a feather pen is used for drugs.
And this is the corresponding passage in the original.

“You were there that night,” said Poirot quietly.
“How do you know, mister?”
“By this.” Poirot took something from his pocket and held it out.
It was the goose quill we had found in the summer-house.
At the sight of it the man’s face changed. He half held out his hand.
“Snow,” said Poirot thoughtfully. “No, my friend, it is empty. It lay where you dropped it in the summer-house that night.”

I don't grasp the context of “Snow” and “No, my friend, it is empty”. What does Poirot want to say about the feather pen?

“Snow” refers to a drug in the form of a white powder:

snow, n. 5.d. 1914– slang (originally U.S.). Cocaine; occasionally heroin or morphine.
Oxford English Dictionary.

In The Murder of Roger Ackroyd, it is heroin that is meant:

He held out to me the little quill. I looked at it curiously. Then a memory of something I had read stirred in me.
Poirot, who had been watching my face, nodded. ‘Yes, heroin, “snow.” Drug-takers carry it like this, and sniff it up the nose.’
‘Diamorphine hydrochloride,’ I murmured mechanically.
‘This method of taking the drug is very common on the other side.† Another proof, if we wanted one, that the man came from Canada or the States.’
Agatha Christie (1926). The Murder of Roger Ackroyd, chapter 13. London: Collins.
† The other side of the Atlantic, Poirot means.

Note that “quill” or “quill pen” is the usual term in English, not “feather pen”, as in the simplified version of the novel. A “quill” is the hollow shaft of a feather, usually employed in a pen as a reservoir for ink, but in Ackroyd as a straw for snorting (insufflating) a drug in powdered form. Since quills are no longer as commonly available as they were in the 1920s, plastic straws or rolled-up banknotes are now used.
When Poirot says “No, my friend, it is empty”, he means that he knows that Kent reached for the quill because it belonged to him, and he thought it might still contain some of the heroin that he had stored there.
